# IBM Bluemix - Unable to import JSON through the Mobile Data GUI

Tags: json, cordova, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm working on Manage data in IBM Bluemix from your hybrid mobile apps with IBM plugins for Apache Cordova. I have couple of problems with an ibm bluemix unable to get the appsecretid and unable to import JSON data to MobileData, But able to import image on to the MobileData.

I'm following this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-bluemix-cordova-plugin/index.html to store data onto the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application secret can be found in Mobile Application Security Dashboard on the Bluemix Console
[image]

For your second question I can't help much without a better idea of what errors you're encountering. The documentation link on that page is broken though, please find the correct [Importing Data document here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/mobiledata/index.html#importdata). If what you find there doesn't help you please let me know what specific error you're hitting on data import, if it is an issue with your specific json, and any network console debug you have from the attempt.

Regards

Comment: Thanks. For Second question want to import json on to the Mobiledata like follows this json data {
"Name":"lenova",
"Kind":"laptop",
"Size":"3kg",
}                                                                                        The error it is dispaying here Cannot get data classes.

Comment: Hmm that sounds like it may be a server issue. Could you please let me know your application route and id so I can check our logs? Regards.

Comment: Additionally please ensure that your json is valid. The string you posted is not valid due to the comma after the last item. `{"Name":"lenova", "Kind":"laptop", "Size":"3kg"}` would be the valid form of that json.

Comment: routeid:http://BluemixApp123.mybluemix.net and id:62804ca0-ad02-4169-abf1-abbe81f160df

Comment: Can you please help me out what is Data Classes in Mobile Data? How can we create this dataclasses. I corrected the json still it is not importing.

Comment: Looking at the logs it appears the import is failing due to a caching issue within your service instance. Please try wiping your browser's cache of bluemix. Additionally I would recommend restarting your application which can be done through the green button on the overview page for your app.

Comment: I cleared my browser's cache still i got the error like can not get storage. I even tried in IE and firefox browser as well but same error.  I can able to import images on to it.

Comment: Able to import .sql , .txt, .png files apart from JSON file able to import everything.

Comment: Imports of json are a bit special, I would still recommend restarting your application. If that does not resolve it please try deleting your Mobile Data service and acquiring a new one through the catalog. I apologize for the trouble but I don't think it is a server issue as we can't recreate on our end and I don't think you are using the tool incorrectly.

Comment: @JamesYoungIBM - Which link is broken? I am happy to get it fixed, but a broken link checker didn't show anything broken.

Comment: @JamesYoungIBM - Still I Experence the same.

Comment: Importing JSON data to Mobile Data is now working for me.I justed removed my old application and recreated it. :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it, sometimes recreation is the easiest work-around. @BillWentworth the broken link is in the Mobile Data dashboard under Manage Data ''For more information about the file formats you can import, see
importing data into the mobile data service.''